No native library is found for os.name=Mac and os.arch=aarch64
how can I fix this on Mac m1? (I am using IntelliJ)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: No native library is found for os.name=Mac and os.arch=aarch64. path=/org/sqlite/native/Mac/aarch64
    at org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.loadSQLiteNativeLibrary(SQLiteJDBCLoader.java:333)
    at org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.initialize(SQLiteJDBCLoader.java:64)
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.load(NativeDB.java:63)
    at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:235)
    ... 26 more


SQLite is a native app, not a Java app.
On a Mac with an Apple Silicon chip (M1, M2, M3) that is built on ARM chip architecture (AArch64), you need to install an edition of SQLite built for the Apple Silicon chip.
Or, less recommended, you can install an edition of SQLite built for a Mac with Intel chips along with installing Apple’s Rosetta 2 chip-emulation technology.

Personally, I would drop SQLite, and instead use a pure-Java database engine such as H2 Database Engine.
